# Does a 0% on Purchases Credit Card include cashback from a store?

Tags: credit-card

Simple question really, but couldn't find the answer whilst search so thought I would ask here.

Basically, I have a 0% on Purchases Credit Card and I was wondering if I bought something on it from a Supermarket, then asked for cashback would that still be classed as a 0% Purchase? As technically it goes on your receipt and is classed as a Purchase, even though you got cash back.

The card isn't 0% for Withdrawals, so thought I'd check before trying it.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you mean a small cash rebate from store or that you returned the item for cash?

Comment: Sure, I mean for example purchasing some small groceries (such as Eggs and Milk) and then when the cashier asks if I would like "cashback" whilst paying for my card, I say yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have asked for "cash back" at the register it has been treated as part of the purchase, and not as a cash advance. The monthly credit card bill always notes that by cash advance balance is always zero.

I have noticed that one of the cards (Discover) does know about the cash back because the description on the website for the transaction does mention the amount of cash back I received. But still the cash advance balance is zero.

The amount you can receive in cash back is based on the limits set by the store and the card company.

Comment: I know that store purchases made with a debit card can have up to $50(?) cash back. But when I use a charge card I've never been offered cash. Is this common?

Comment: My local grocery store allows this, and so do their major competitors. Of course if I use the self service register I am never offered cash back.

Comment: The store in question for me was Sainsburys, the offer (like most others) up to £50 cashback. I asked for it whilst paying my Credit Card, but they told me that cashback wasn't available on the card. Oh well! Seems they cottoned on to my "loophole" on withdrawal interest :). Thanks again.

Comment: For Discover it is a special perk called "Cash Over", only offered at certain locations https://www.discover.com/credit-cards/member-benefits/cash-over-purchases.html